# C# How to increase performance of Method Averaging Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, average

So before i post the code i'll explain some varibales / arrays that are used in the code

```
// random generated values in this array  
DataPoint[] file = new DataPoint[2592000];

// 240 values generated by avg values from file
DataPoint[] TempBuffer = new DataPoint[240];

//stores values (2, 4, 16, 180, 360) depends on scaling case
DataPoint[] TempBuffer2 = new DataPoint[scaling];


// is a value that im changing with a mouse click
// to 2, 4, 16, 180 or 360
int scaling

// dummy values for file are created like this:

public void createDummyValues()
        {
            Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; file.Length > i; i++)
            {
                double value = rnd.Next(1, 31);
                if (value == 25)
                {
                    value = 9999;
                }

                file[i] = new DataPoint(unixTimestamp, value);
                unixTimestamp--;
            }
        }
```

In my code I'm taking 2-360 values from file, fetching them to one and adding the new value to the TempBuffer. I'm doing that till the TempBuffer is full (240 Values).
My code works but lacks of performance especially for 180 and 360 scaling values it takes ages to complete than.

Code:

```
DataPoint[] TempBuffer = new DataPoint[240];
                DataPoint[] file = new DataPoint[2592000];
                DataPoint[] TempBuffer2 = new DataPoint[scaling];
                Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;

                for (int a = 0; a < 240; a++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < scaling; i++)
                    {
                        bool exists = true;
                        if (exists != (Array.Exists(file, element => element.XValue == unixTimestamp - i)))
                        {
                            TempBuffer2 = TempBuffer2.Skip(1).Concat(new DataPoint[] { new DataPoint((UnixTODateTime(unixTimestamp - i)).ToOADate(), 0) }).ToArray();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DataPoint point = Array.Find(file, element => element.XValue == unixTimestamp - i);
                            TempBuffer2 = TempBuffer2.Skip(1).Concat(new DataPoint[] { new DataPoint((UnixTODateTime(unixTimestamp - i)).ToOADate(), point.YValues) }).ToArray();
                        }
                    }

                    DataPoint tpoint = Array.Find(TempBuffer2, element => element.YValues[0] == 9999);
                    if (tpoint != null)
                    {
                        double avgTime = TempBuffer2.Average(x => x.XValue);
                        TempBuffer = TempBuffer.Skip(1).Concat(new DataPoint[] { new DataPoint(avgTime, tpoint.YValues[0]) }).ToArray();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        double avgRTT = TempBuffer2.Average(x => x.YValues[0]);
                        double avgTime = TempBuffer2.Average(x => x.XValue);

                        TempBuffer = TempBuffer.Skip(1).Concat(new DataPoint[] { new DataPoint(avgTime, avgRTT) }).ToArray();
                    }
                    unixTimestamp = unixTimestamp - scaling;
                }
```

How could I improve the performance of my code? Why is it so slow?

Comment: "My code works but lacks of performance especially for 180 and 360 scaling values it takes ages to complete than" How did you prove that? Did you *measure* it? Preferably by using a profiler that indicates *where* you´re losing time. Maybe it´s not that code you think of.

Comment: I'm going to make an informed guess here and state that it's probably your use of `Array.Find` within loops. `Array.Find` is an O(n) operation. Using it within loops will lead to nasty computational complexity. It's going to be much faster to make lookups of your array searches up front, either with `.ToDictionary` or `.ToLookup`, so that you can do O(1) searches over your data.

Comment: Array.Exist / Array.Find in loop is actually slow. You should use dictionaries for faster search. Next: TempBuffer / TempBuffer2 reallocation using LINQ. That produces unwanted memory pressure for garbage collector and extra time spent on this. In your situation (remove first item from buffer and add new one to the end) linked list will be more efficient

Comment: `Array.Exists` is similarly an O(n) complexity operation, so that should also be factored out.

Comment: So, you might `var xIndex=file.ToDictionary(element => element.XValue)` outside of your loop, then it's efficient to `xIndex.ContainsKey(unixTimestamp - i)`, for instance.